# How to write filepath on PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using PyAutoGUI to type this filepath :

```
 pyautogui.write(r'C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\PythonDev\Instagram\imagename.jpg', interval=0.1)
```

However, despite the fact there is "r'" in the beginning of my code, i still have a problem :

[image]

How can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: alex i have tried your line of code its working fine.

Comment: Then share more code so that i can see where is problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following
`pyautogui.write('C:\\Users\\Alex\\Dropbox\\PythonDev\\Instagram\\imagename.jpg', interval=0.1)`

OR

`pyautogui.typewrite("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Dropbox\\PythonDev\\Instagram\\imagename.jpg", interval=0.1)`